# Powershell - Change display format in SharePoint Site column from friendly to standard

Tags: 2013, list, powershell, column

How can I change the display format from friendly to standard?

I want to change this on all lists in the solution

[image]

```
$sites = Get-SPSite "http://company.com/sites/testdelete/"
$created = "Created"

foreach ($spsite in $sites)
{
  $sitelists = foreach ($web in $spsite.AllWebs) 
  {
    foreach($list in $web.lists)
    { 
       foreach($list in $web.lists)
       { 
           $column = $list.Fields[$created]
           $column.FriendlyDisplayFormat = "Disabled"
           $column.Update()

       }
    }
  }
#$sitelists |select Title
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how Standard format looks? Also which column you want to change?

Comment: If you choose to use friendly, then all lists will be formated (date) like facebook.  (yesterday, today, 6 min ago..) . I only want to change this setting from friendly to standard

Comment: Try setting the property to 1, `$column.FriendlyDisplayFormat = 1`. This is enumeration as we can see here: [SPDateTimeFieldFriendlyFormatType enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spdatetimefieldfriendlyformattype(v=office.15).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the property to 1

```
$column.FriendlyDisplayFormat = 1
```

This is enumeration type as we can see here: [SPDateTimeFieldFriendlyFormatType enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spdatetimefieldfriendlyformattype(v=office.15).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This method worked for me.

```
$column.FriendlyDisplayFormat = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPDateTimeFieldFriendlyFormatType]::Disabled
```